# Conditional checking of "datatable checkboxes" in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, datatables

Hi I'm trying to create a table that consists of checkboxes. And each row has its own class and ID.

```
$('#niisPrprtyCoverageTable').dataTable({
    "data" : coverageList,
    "columns" : [ { 
        "data" : "seqNo",
     "visible" : false
    }, {
        "data" : "coverageCode"
    }, {
        "data" : "coverageName"
    }, {
        "data" : "coverageCode",
        "width" : "80px",
        "className" : "text-center",
        render : function(data, type, row) {
            var arrData = data.split(";");
            var coverageCd = arrData[0];
            var coverageRel = nvl(arrData[1], coverageCd);
            data = '<input class="'+coverageRel+'" id="'+coverageCd+'" type="checkbox" onClick="addToArray('
                + coverageCd
                + ','
                + coverageRel
                + ')">';
            return data;
        }
    } ],
    "searching" : false,
    "bLengthChange" : false,
    "iDisplayLength" : 15 ,
    "bSort" : false,
    "columnDefs" : [ {
        "targets" : [ 1, 2 ],
        "className" : "left"
    }, {
        "targets" : [ 2 ],
        "width" : "150px",
    }, {
        "targets" : [ 1 ],
        "width" : "100px",
    }, {
        "targets" : [ 3 ],
        "width" : "50px",
        "className" : "text-center"
    } ]
});
niisPrptyCoverageTable = $('#niisPrprtyCoverageTable').DataTable();

$('#select-all').on('click', function(){
    alert('ss');
    // Get all rows with search applied
    var rows = niisPrptyCoverageTable.rows({ 'search': 'applied' }).nodes();
    // Check/uncheck checkboxes for all rows in the table
    $('input[type="checkbox"]', rows).prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

What should happen is, if I check the main row, all the rows under his 'code or id' should be checked also.

It works but only on the first page
[image]

but doesn't work on the second page of the datatable
[image]

```
var array = [];
function addToArray(coverageCd, coverageRel) {
    var rows = niisPrptyCoverageTable.rows('.'+coverageRel).nodes().className;
    $('input[class='+coverageCd+']', rows).prop('checked', '#'+coverageCd.checked);
}
```

Comment: how to differentiate _I check the main row_ and others ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`$()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/$()) API method to get access to elements on all pages, not just current page.

For example:

```
var array = [];
function addToArray(coverageCd, coverageRel) {
    var rows = niisPrptyCoverageTable.rows('.'+coverageRel).nodes().className;
    niisPrptyCoverageTable.$('input[class='+coverageCd+']', rows).prop('checked', '#'+coverageCd.checked);
}
```

Alternatively see [jQuery DataTables Checkboxes](https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/) extension for easier handling of checkboxes in a table powered by jQuery DataTables.